# Show that the Lie algebra homomorphism $f$ cannot be induced by a smooth Lie group homomorphism.

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

> Consider the Lie algebras $\mathfrak {so} (3)$ and $\mathfrak {su} (2)$ and let $f : \mathfrak {so} (3) \longrightarrow \mathfrak {su} (2)$ be the Lie algebra homomorphism given by $$f \left (\begin{pmatrix} 0 & x & y \\ -x & 0 & z \\ -y & -z & 0 \end{pmatrix} \right ) = \frac {1} {2} \begin{pmatrix} iz & y - ix \\ -y - ix & -iz \end{pmatrix}$$ $x,y,z \in \mathbb R.$ Show that there does not exist any smooth Lie group homomorphism $F : SO (3) \longrightarrow SU(2)$ such that $F(\exp (X)) = \exp (f(X)),$ for all $X \in \mathfrak {so} (3).$

If we can show that then by Lie's theorem it yields an alternative way of showing that the matrix Lie group $SO(3)$ is not simply connected. But I am having hard time showing the non-existence of such a smooth $F.$ Could anyone help me out here?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose there exists such a homomorphism $F$. Then take $$X=2\pi
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Note that $\text{Exp}(X)=I$ and since $F$ is a homomorphism $F(I)=I'$ (identity in $SU(2))$.

On the other hand $$f(X)=\pi\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -i  \\
-i & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

And $$\text{Exp}(f(X))=-I'$$

Leading to a contradiction.

Comment: Why $\exp (X) = I$? Note that $\exp$ is locally diffeomorphic  near $0$ and hence so is $\log$ near $I.$ So if you take log in both sides it follows that $X = 0.$ So doesn't it imply that no non-zero matrix exponentiates to $I.$

Comment: @AnilBagchi But this isn't near $0$. Consider the usual complex exponential/logarithm: $\exp(2\pi i) = 1$. All you've found is that the only answer near to $0$ is $0$ but $\exp$ is distinctly not injective so there are other answers. Indeed you could argue the reason the answer here works is the lack of injectivity of $\exp$

Comment: @AnilBagchi: See the above answer. Also you could calculate it explicitly to confirm it, it should be straightforward (You could also check the Rodrigues formula for a quick route, which is what I did). More generally, the Exp map will not be injective (even onto the connected component) if the Lie group is compact (like in the case of SO(3)); This is because the domain of the Exp map is a vector space (Lie algebra).